# Plastic SCM integration with Maven

Tags: maven, plasticscm

Is it possible to use Plastic SCM as repository for Maven projects? If so how to do it? Not able to find good resources regarding the same. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately Plastic SCM is not supported... https://maven.apache.org/scm/scms-overview.html The question is what exactly is needed in relationship with Maven?

Comment: Technically you can use Plastic SCM to host a Maven repository but I see problems upcoming related to making a release etc.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks. Will figure out a workaround.

Comment: Just use git ... makes life easier and is supported on a lot of platforms etc. tools supporting it as well...